# Creating a data table without using a common data source in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis-2012

i want to create a table without using SQL or file data source, for now i found one path but if there is another way to solve it i will be happy to hear.
for now i decided to build strcut list in script task and pass the data table to the object variable but i have no idea how to make from this object variable a table i can use.
this is what i placed in the code -

```
    List<TableInfo> Table_List = new List<TableInfo>
    {
        new TableInfo("aa",1),
        new TableInfo("bb",2)
    };
    Dts.Variables["User::TableList"].Value = Table_List ;
```

thanks for any assistance

Answer (score -1):

So i found a solution - i added script task as source ,added columns to the task, build data table in the script and put it to the script columns, from there its steight forward as cash table created inside ssis without any data source